# How can I get more workers?

Tags: bead-machine-punktasia

I've unlocked the school, factory, and depot, and have a fairly balanced system that continually outputs excess money, vending machines, and coils.  However, my workers seem to be stuck at 8/25.  To progress, I need 10.

How can I get more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems, to produce new workers, you need your school switched on and working, and high enough bead production to ensure the new worker won't slack of, i.e. 7k beads per possible worker. Therefore for 10 workers you need 70k beads per tick.

Keep in mind that to keep workers, you don't have to keep the school on.